# To find all groups of finite order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I know that there are 6 abelian groups of order 540 as follows
$$\mathbb{Z}_{540}; \ \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{270}; \ \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{180}; \ \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{90}; \ \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{60}; \ \mathbb{Z}_{3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{30}\ ,$$ where $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}_+,\  \mathbb{Z}_k \cong \mathbb{Z}/\left\langle k \right\rangle \ .$

But I think I haven't yet understood the way to determinate these results. Can you help me?

Comment: There are [$119$ groups of order $540$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_540).  I think you meant to restrict to abelian groups.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I forgot that!

Answer (score 0):

These are abelian groups. For the non-abelian case, you need to invoke the machinery of semi-direct products, and look at homomorphisms to the automorphism group. For groups of large order, this can be come quite heavy on case-work, but you may try to work it out if you like.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Here's a link that should contain some examples for how to use this machinery to classify groups.

http://www.math.columbia.edu/~bayer/S09/ModernAlgebra/semidirect.pdf

Now I think what you're trying to do, is use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. This relates the prime factorization of the order to the groups of that order.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups

The page is for finite groups, but generalizes to just finite generation, where there may be powers of $\mathbb{Z}$ as well as finite cyclic groups.

Comment: Even semidirect products are not enough. For example, the quaternion group of order $8$ is not a non-trivial semidirect product.

Comment: @ Alfred Yerger Yes, I want to find the abelian groups, but your answer is so nice. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ verret Yes, you right! Thank you!